# Is it grammatically correct to put "more" instead of "more of" immediately before a predicative noun in this sentence?

Tags: grammar-myths

I came across this sentence and I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct.

> Are the dinosaurs of Jurassic World more fact or fiction?

The word "fact" and "fiction" are nouns. I'd use "more of" instead of "more" and I would say "a fact" and "a fiction". Anyway, I don't think it is right to say "That meal is more breakfast."

Comment: I would say the sentence is idiomatically correct.

Comment: `a fiction` doesn't really make sense, at least at a glance.

Comment: @StephenS: No, "a fiction" is fine. But both fact and fiction are better without an article in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence

> Are the dinosaurs of Jurassic World more fact or fiction?

is correct and idiomatic, you could also write

> Are the dinosaurs of Jurassic World more **of a** fact or **a** fiction?

if you really wanted to use articles.

In your second sentence

> That meal is more breakfast.

has the meaning that you had some breakfast and *then had more to eat for breakfast*, however

> That meal is more **of a** breakfast.

describes your meal as being *more like* breakfast than say lunch.